# How to reuse the dataframe in a join

Tags: python, pyspark

Might be a really bold question, but how would be possible to reuse the dataframe in a join?

For example lets say I have got the following scenario:

```
df.join(df1, df.product_type == df1.id, "left")
  .join(df1, df.deal_type == df1.id, "left")
```

Please note that the above is the part of the bigger script consisting of mutiple functions.

It seems that only the data from the first join is getting returned. So the dataframe is not persisted or reused.

Many thanks

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data. Please provide small sample of df1 and show what you expect the output of the two joins to look like!  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a typo somewhere in your code. I tried your commands on sample dataframes and got the data from  both joins as output

```
data = [(1, 1, 1),
        (1, 1, 2),
        (1, 2, 2),
        (1, 2, 3),
        (1, 3, 5)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["id", "product_type", "deal_type"])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)], schema=["id", "just_col"])

df_out = (df
          .join(df1, df.product_type == df1.id, "left")
          .join(df1, df.deal_type == df1.id, "left"))
```

for df as
[image]

and df1 as

[image]

df_out is

[image]